# Proving Progress for STLC with Linear and Unrestricted Types

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus

In [this](http://mitp-content-server.mit.edu:18180/books/content/sectbyfn?collid=books_pres_0&id=1104&fn=9780262162289_sch_0001.pdf) paper Walker presents an extension of STLC with linear and unrestricted types. The proof of type soundness is left as an exercise to the reader. I encountered difficulty when attempting to prove progress (in a theorem prover):

$$ \vdash (S_1,e_1) ~\Rightarrow~ \textsf{value}{(e_1)} ~\lor~ \exists S_2 \exists e_2.~ (S_1,e_1) \rightarrow (S_2,e_2)$$

The relevant typing and evaluation relations can be found on pages 6-17 of the linked document. If we attempt to prove progress by induction on the typing derivation, we encounter the following problem: there is a typing rule for variables, but variables are not values and the evaluation relation says nothing about variables.

Now adding a variable rule to the evaluation relation is the wrong solution. For example, we don't want to reduce $(\varnothing,\mathsf{un~true})$ to $(x\mapsto\mathsf{un~true},x)$, and the immediately reduce $x$ to $\mathsf{un~true}$ by looking up its value in the store. The two solutions I am considering are (1) adding variables to the set of values; and (2) requiring that terms reduce to *variables* or can take a step in the statement of the progress lemma. Ideally the correction would reflect the original intention of the author. It is also possible that I am misunderstanding the paper or language.

Comment: Could you give a precise reference for the paper? The link does not work for me.

Comment: The reference is "Substructural Type Systems" by David Walker in *Advanced Topics in Types and Programming Languages*. Apologies about the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables can be considered as values if the evaluation strategy is call-by-value. Otherwise said, it only makes sense to substitute a variable with a value (in call-by-value). I am unable to check if that is the case in the paper you refer to since I can't access it.